# Adding two arrays?

Tags: c++, c, arduino

In the Arduino IDE, I'd like to add the contents of two existing arrays like this:

```
#define L0 { {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0} }
#define L1 { {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0} }
```

should become

```
   int myarray[3][4] = { {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0} }
```

How would I go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using a loop or two?

Comment: wrap the array in a class, initialise the content in the constructor, and create a function with a static instance variable of the class, return a reference to the wrapped array

Comment: @lurscher -- So simple!  Why didn't I think of that??

Comment: (Nick, he's kidding.  This is an incredibly simple problem.)

Comment: @lurscher - The correct answer is clearly `Array(L0)+Array(L1)`. How you implement the Array class is an exercise for the reader :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thy this;

```
const int a[3][4] = { {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0} };
const int b[3][4] = { {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0} };

int c[3][4];

const int* pa = &a[0][0];
const int* pb = &b[0][0];
int* pc = &c[0][0];

for(int i = 0; i < 3 * 4; ++i)
{
    *(pc + i) = *(pa + i) + *(pb + i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confused about how to go *access* the arrays `L0` and `L1` since they are defined as macros. Just assign them to arrays since the preprocessor will simply replace them:

```
int l[][4]=L0;
int m[][4]=L1;
```

Preprocessor will replace `L0` and `L1` with their values and compiler will only see them as:

```
int l[][4]={ {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 2, 0, 0} };
int m[][4]={ {0, 0, 0, 5}, {0, 0, 0, 6}, {0, 0, 7, 0} };
```

Now, you can use `l` & `m` to access the elements of array. Should easy enough from here to add two arrays :)